# Query Wikidata countries - how to return labels in all languages

Tags: sparql, wikidata

How do I query Wikidata countries in order to return the label of all countries in all available languages?

I am able to run the query by specifying the languages I want (e.g. I successfully asked for a list of countries with the English and Arabic labels). But can I ask it to return a label column for all languages? If so, how?

## Countries in English and Arabic

```
SELECT ?country ?label_en ?label_ar
WHERE
{
  ?country wdt:P31 wd:Q6256.
  ?country rdfs:label ?label_en filter (lang(?label_en) = "en").
  ?country rdfs:label ?label_ar filter (lang(?label_ar) = "ar").
}
```

[Sparql Query link](https://query.wikidata.org/#%23Countries%20in%20English%20and%20Arabic%0ASELECT%20%3Fcountry%20%3Flabel_en%20%3Flabel_ar%0AWHERE%0A%7B%0A%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ6256.%0A%20%20%3Fcountry%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel_en%20filter%20%28lang%28%3Flabel_en%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29.%0A%20%20%3Fcountry%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel_ar%20filter%20%28lang%28%3Flabel_ar%29%20%3D%20%22ar%22%29.%0A%7D)

Comment: I don't get it. Do you want to get labels in all languages? If so, just remove the filter. Or does this not work?

Answer (score 2):

As @AKSW said in a comment, you can get the list of all country names in all languages by removing the filter from your query:

```
SELECT ?country ?label
WHERE
{
  ?country wdt:P31 wd:Q6256.
  ?country rdfs:label ?label
}
```

You might also (perhaps) want to know the identity of each language being returned, and the English word for each country being named:

```
SELECT ?country ?label (lang(?label) as ?label_lang) ?countryLabel
WHERE
{
  ?country wdt:P31 wd:Q6256.
  ?country rdfs:label ?label .
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```